# Thread has been aborted when upgrading site collection from SP 2010 -> 2013

Tags: 2013, site-collection, upgrade

I am upgrading a site collection from SP 2010 to SP 2013. It's rather large about +- 100gb. I performed the same steps on smaller site collections before and all worked fine. Now I suspect the "thread has been aborted" is caused by following ULS log

> Application error when access /_layouts/siteupgrade.aspx, Error=Request timed out.

So my first instinct was increase the timeout value in my web.config however the execution timeout parameters are all similar to following

> < httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />

which is an hour and the error does not take an hour to take place.

Is this the correct parameter for this problem or am I searching down the wrong path here?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade the site an upgrade log and upgrade error file should be created (in same location as ULS logs) you need to review those logs to find more details about your specific problem. Review specifically full upgrade log file, not just the error one as it will contain more details. You may want to review as well the event viewer.

Have a look at this MS guidance: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/troubleshoot-database-upgrade-issues-in-sharepoint-2013